# Sort array of File[] based on file.lastModified

Tags: java, android

I have a array of files.

```
File[] toSort = videoFiles.listFiles();
```

I need to sort them based on lastModified. How do I achieve it in Android.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
File[] toSort = videoFiles.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(toSort, new Comparator<File>(){
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
         return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how I should assign it to my new Array ? I mean File[] sortedArray = ?

Comment: you don't need to assign it to anything.  The original array object will be sorted.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: there is no difference after doing it

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that sorts the way you want:

```
public class LastModifiedComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
    }
}
```

Then you could use [Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-)

```
LastModifiedComparator comp = new LastModifiedComparator();
Arrays.sort(toSort, comp);
```

Comment: this is from API19 only. I use API 16 as min